# Structures in C++ *

Tags: c++, structure

Probably a dumb question, but I'm just curious. What do the variables ***temp** and ***perm** mean in this structure?

```
struct process {
    int id;
    char name;
} *temp, *perm;
```

Comment: syntax diagrams! It's variables of type of pointer to process object (struct), obviously

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short version of

```
struct process {
    int id;
    char name;
};

process *temp;
process *perm;
```

This declares a struct type named process and then declares two variables which are pointers to process structs.